# C# Asp.Net EntityFrameworkCore 5.0 _ManageNav.cshtml.g.cs deletes using statement on rebuild

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

I am doing a demo project in asp.net MVC with entityframework 5.0.

I created a custom user class that inherits IdentityUser, and replaced it in the whole project after scaffolding all identity files. Now I'm having a weird problem I don't understand why is happening.

For this to work I had to add using ApplicationName.Data, where this new class file is stored, to all files.
This works as intended but when I add this to _ManageNav.cshtml.g.cs, and build and run it works the first time, but then when I rebuild it removes the statement so that I have to re-add it for every build.

This is quite annoying so if anyone could shed some light on why this one file seems to be removing this using statement on every other build, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

After researching what these files are and closely inspecting the code, I was able to fix this issue by adding the statement to the the page file "_ManageNav.cshtml" instead.
At this point this seems obvious, but the visual studio error log threw me off with this one.

Comment: a general advice all files which are not conform with the default naming are most likely auto generated, therefore they get generated with every build.